# Best way to add and subtract Epoch Time?

Tags: python

I am writing a TimeTracker python program and It's pretty much done. The only issue is that there is no way of looking at the total time. When I try to add epoch time It doesn't work.

When I add, it adds the entire thing, not just the seconds. If I want to add lets say 00:00:01 to 00:00:02, I get 06:00:03. I have a function that simplifies epoch time.

```py
def simplify(_time):
    return time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.localtime(_time))
```

I think it's because if I'm only changing 2 digits, and I add the rest, It doesen't ignore the fact that only 2 digits have changed.

What is the best way to do math operations to Epoch Timestamps

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert durations (such as 5 minutes, or 1 hour, or 24 hours) into [Python timedelta objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects).  Then you can add up all the time delta objects and get a sensible answer:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> durations = [datetime.timedelta(hours=1), 
                 datetime.timedelta(hours=2),       
                 datetime.timedelta(hours=3)]
>>> sum(durations, datetime.timedelta()) == datetime.timedelta(hours=6)                                                                                                         
True
```

It does not really make sense to add two time points (e.g. `datetime.datetime` instances).  For example, what is the sum of these two times?

```
2020-01-05 19:08:55
2020-01-06 10:15:30
```

It's not really a sensible question.

Comment: The use of the subtraction is to find the amount of time between something. For example whats the elapsed time between 1:00 and 2:00. On hour. But, I have multiple of these. I want to find the total elapsed time by adding the elapsed time together.

Comment: Good news: when you subtract two `datetime.datetime` objects, you naturally get a `timedelta` object.  For example:  `datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 5, 20, 5) - datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 5, 19, 40)` gives `datetime.timedelta(seconds=1500)`, which is 25 minutes.